# Подключение по ssh, linux

Tags: linux, debian, ssh, ssh-key

Есть хост, логин и 2 ключа, один с расширением .pub 
Не получается подключится к данному серверу, добавлял ключи в ./authorized_keys/
Все равно спрашивает пароль
Подскажите пожалуйста, инструкцию по подключению к удаленному серверу

Comment: Как подключаетесь и где расположен ./authorized_keys/? authorized_keys - у вас файл или папка?

Comment: Возможно ты пытаешься в папку authorized_keys кидать ключи, .pub ключ нужно переименовать в authorized_keys и кинуть в папку ~/.ssh А еще есть удобный ssh-copy-id, если с одного linux сервера устанавливаешь ключи на другой.

Comment: подключаюсь /ssh login@host, да authorized_keys была папка и там был ключ, переименовал ключ и кинул в .ssh, все равно чего-то не заводится, требует пароль

Comment: @user205598 А что и на какой машине вы кладете. .ssh/authorized_keys должен быть на машине к которой вы подключаетесь, у пользователя под которым подключаетесь. На той машине С которой идет подключение, закрытый ключ должен быть в .ssh/id_rsa. Вы можете при подключении указать ssh ключ -v он выдаст кучу отладочной информации из которой можно узнать и о попытках обмена ключами

Answer (score 4, accepted):

authorized_keys - это **файл**, который должен быть расположен в папке ~/.ssh того пользователя, из под которого вы хотите попадать на сервер. Т.е. если у вас нет вот такого **файла**, его нужно создать

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Путь к файлу уточните в директиве AuthorizedKeysFile, конфигурационного файла OpenSSH. Если нужна папка .ssh, а её нет - её тоже нужно создать.

В файл нужно записать публичный ключ (с расширением .pub), например так

```
cat id_rsa.pub >> ~/.ssh/authorized_keys
```

Это команда допишет ключ из файла id_rsa.pub в конец файла ~/.ssh/authorized_keys, не перезатирая уже существующие в ней ключи (если они там есть).

Дополнительно следует убедиться, что в конфигурационном файле SSH-сервера включена директива PubkeyAuthentication

```
PubkeyAuthentication yes
```

Answer (score 1):

На стороне сервера в папке `~/.ssh` есть файл `id_rsa.pub`, он содержит ключ который должен быть на стороне клиента в папке `~/.ssh` в файле `authorized_keys`.

Скорее всего в `authorized_keys` нет ключа и *ssh* пытается авторизоваться с помощью пароля.

Чтобы исключить авторизацию по паролю можете добавить на сервере в файл `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
PasswordAuthentication no
```

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте команду:

```
ssh-copy-id '-i /home/[путь до папки юзера]/.ssh/id_rsa.pub user@server
```

Команда добавит ключ на сервер

Comment: Проблема что понадобится пароль